# Can anybody explain the following JavaScript code from jCarousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, logical-operators

I've been writing JS for a while, and I have been trying to debug the jQuery jCarousel plugin for IE7 compatibility.  A lot of the variables are obfuscated, which is OK, but I have never seen syntax like this:

```
scroll: function (a, c) {
    !this.locked && !this.animating && (this.pauseAuto(), this.animate(this.pos(a), c))
}
```

It seems like some sort of shorthand notation, but I've never come across anything like this.
Similarly,

```
for (var a = function (a) {
    i.get(a).each(function () {
        h(i, this, a, b, c)
    })
}, k = d; k <= f; k++)  {
    k !== null && !(k >= j && k <= e) && a(k)
}
```

I have never seen a function being assigned as the iterator, and again the block statement inside looks like the first example.  I know we all strive to save a few bytes when we write our code, but to me this feverish attempt comes at a cost of utter confusion and bewilderment to other programmers.  Can anybody can give me a simple, "longhand" alternative / thorough explanation of what's happening?  I always want to know more about this language and how it works, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) evaluates each expression until it finds one which is truthy, which it returns. If none are truthy, it returns the last one.

The [`,` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates both it's operands and returns the second one (no matter what they return).

So in the first example, it's basically saying:

```
scroll: function (a, c) {
    if (!this.locked && !this.animating) {
        this.pauseAuto();
        this.animate(this.pos(a), c)
    }
}
```

As for the second example, it's important to note the iteration is over the `k` variable, not `a`:

```
var a = function (a) {
    i.get(a).each(function () {
        h(i, this, a, b, c)
    })
};

for (k = d; k <= f; k++)  {
    if (k !== null && !(k >= j && k <= e)) {
        a(k)
    }
}
```

For the second example, don't forget it's [possible to define multiple variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) in one `var` statement using the `,`:

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3;
```

---

It's important to know that the *developer himself* isn't minimizing the code like this; he's writing [normal source code](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/blob/master/src/jquery.jcarousel.js) with meaningful variable names in easy to read blocks. When it comes to release time, he'll run the minified version through a minifier ([UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS), [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) etc) to get the reduced code.

Comment: Just to be sure, the argument in the function assigned to var a is a previously declared instance of var a, right?

Comment: @moonDogDog: No, inside that function `a` will be the parameter passed  (in this case `a(k)` is ran inside the `for` loop, so inside the function `a` will be the value of `k`).

Answer (score 0):

Because of short-circuit evaluation:

```
a && b && (c, d, e);
```

is basically equivalent to:

```
if (a) {
    if (b) {
        c;
        d;
        e;
    }
}
```

And the value of the expression will be **e**.

In the second example, the function is not an iterator, he is just using the first position of the for loop to initialize an anonymous function and then assign it to **a**.

The author of that code is just being overly terse. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

**Update**:

Here is a re-write of the second example that should be functionally equivalent:

```
function a (a) {
    i.get(a).each(function () {
        h(i, this, a, b, c)
    });
}

for (k = d; k <= f; k++)  {
    if ((k !== null) && (!(k >= j && k <= e))) {
        a(k);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK but what kind of call is 
(this.pauseAuto(), this.animate(this.pos(a), c))
Why is that wrapped in parentheses and how can these functions be comma delimited?

Comment: The parens are grouping, not a function call. Comma means evaluate each element and then return the final elements value.

Comment: Is there a way to catch the value of the returns of each of those groupings on that same line of code?

Comment: Yes. Since assignment also has a return value in Javascript, you can add assignments to new variables. this.locked() && dosomething(); -> (lck = this.locked()) && dosomething(); The lck global will contain the value.